# Mysql join table with 2 Foriiegn key with same table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have an activity table which has a column named **assigned_to** and a column named **created_by**.
Both are referencing the user table which has a "first name" and "last name" column.

I know we should join the user table twice to get a value for both names ( Assigned to and Created by)

Is there a way I can get all of this data with a single join query?

Comment: The answer lies in the last sentence maybe

Comment: Yeah, But i jus need confirmation from fellow developers

Answer (score 1):

You need to join twice to the `users` table.  The use of table aliases is important:

```
select a.*, ua.name as assigned_name, uc.name as created_name
from activities a left join
     users ua
     on a.assigned_to = ua.user_id left join
     users uc
     on a.created_by = uc.user_id;
```

You want to use `left join` in case one of the columns in `activities` is not populated.

Comment: Thanks. I know this and already mentioned it in my question. Apart from this suggested method, i want to know whether its possible with single join query.

Comment: Gordon just showed you a single join query. Use the aliases to get what you want.

Comment: @Drew If i'm not wrong, he joined the users table twice not once.

Comment: @Prem . . . This *is* a single query.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. Of course, this is a single query, but joining the same table more than once. I want "single join" query :).